How to resolve error plotting arrows in mplfinance scatter plot
Although I don't consider myself a newbie, I would regard myself as inexperienced with Python. I am new to MPLFinance.
I am tryting to plot trade entry points on a forex mplfinance chart. I have the basic chart running OK. My data is coming from a DataFrame, which is populated from a CSV import. One of the columns called 'Golden_Cross' contains the word 'long', which is the signal I want to plot with an arrow.
I am trying to emulate the percentB_belowzero function in the mplfinance documentation. I understand the jist of what the function does, but some of the details is lost to me. e.g. what is the significance of price[date], and what is previous used for? This may not be important. The below code is what I have so far:
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf
import math

def go_long(df):
    signal   = [math.nan] * len(df)
    print("len(df) = " + str(len(df)))
    print("len(signal) = " + str(len(signal)))
    for i in range(1, len(df)):
        if df['Golden_Cross'].iloc[i] == "long":
            signal.append(df['close'].iloc[i] * 0.99)
        else:
            signal.append(math.nan)
    return signal

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_csv('GBPUSD_MA_Crossover2.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
    df.index.name = 'date'
    
    long_signal = go_long(df)
    apds =  [ mpf.make_addplot(df[['fast_ma', 'slow_ma']], panel=0, title='GBPUSD'),
              # mpf.make_addplot((df['dmi']),panel=1, title='DMI'),
              mpf.make_addplot(long_signal, type = 'scatter', panel=0, markersize=200, marker='^')
            ]
    mpf.plot(df, type= 'candle', tight_layout=True, datetime_format='%Y-%m-%d', volume=False, show_nontrading=False, addplot=apds)

When I run the above code I get the following stack trace (sorry about the formatting):
> len(df) = 381 len(signal) = 381 
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "/data/stuart/Projects/Python/BackTesting/Scratches/charting1.py",
> line 25, in <module>
>     mpf.plot(df, type= 'candle', tight_layout=True, datetime_format='%Y-%m-%d', volume=False, show_nontrading=False,
> addplot=apds)   
File
> "/data/stuart/Projects/Python/Env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mplfinance/plotting.py",
> line 808, in plot
>     ax = _addplot_columns(panid,panels,ydata,apdict,xdates,config,colcount)
>          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
> File "/data/stuart/Projects/Python/Env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mplfinance/plotting.py",
> line 1139, in _addplot_columns
>     ax.scatter(xdates, ydata, s=size, marker=mark, color=color, alpha=alpha, edgecolors=edgecolors, linewidths=linewidths,label=label)
> 
>     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File
> "/data/stuart/Projects/Python/Env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py",
> line 1473, in inner
>     return func(
>            ^^^^^   File "/data/stuart/Projects/Python/Env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py",
> line 4787, in scatter
>     raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size") ValueError: x and y must be the same size

I don't understand the reference to ValueError: x and y must be the same size. My signal list and df Dataframe are the same size (see the print statement output).
Can someone please help me get this code running correctly please.
Best regards, StuartM

as for me your df should have columns with the same number of items  - can't have None, NaN, etc.

what do you have in signal? If you have only one column with values (as y) then it may need another column with dates (as x)

All problem is how you create signal. It creates list with 2 * 381 elements.
You should check len() after creating signal.
You have to create empty list and append new values at the end.
signal = []

for i in range(...):

    signal.append(...)

Or you have to create list with expected size and use index to replace values
signal = [math.nan] * len(df)

for i in range(...):

    signal[i] = ...

But you mix both methods so you create list with double size.

There can be other problem with .append(). You use range(1, len(df)) so it will create 381-1 values instead of 381. So you may need to using .append(math.nan) before loop to put element in place of index 0 - or start with signal = [math.nan]
signal = [math.nan]

for i in range(1, len(df)):

    signal.append(...)


You can do it also with .apply()
def convert(row):
    if row['Golden_Cross'] == "long":
        return row['close'] * 0.99
    else:
        return math.nan
       
signal = df.apply(convert, axis=1).to_list()

or even shorted
def convert(row):
    return row['close'] * 0.99 if row['Golden_Cross'] == "long" else math.nan
       
signal = df.apply(convert, axis=1).to_list()

You could even write it with lambda but it would be long line and less readable.
signal = df.apply(lambda row: row['close'] * 0.99 if row['Golden_Cross'] == "long" else math.nan, axis=1).to_list()


Meanwhile I made minimal working example with random data in code.
Now everyone can simply copy and run it.
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf
import math
import numpy as np

def go_long_1(df):
    signal = [math.nan] * len(df)
    
    for i in range(1, len(df)):
        if df['Golden_Cross'].iloc[i] == "long":
            signal[i] = df['Close'].iloc[i] * 0.99
        #else:
        #    signal[i[ = math.nan)
   
    return signal

def go_long_2(df):
    signal = [math.nan]
    
    for i in range(1, len(df)):
        if df['Golden_Cross'].iloc[i] == "long":
            signal.append(df['Close'].iloc[i] * 0.99)
        else:
            signal.append(math.nan)
   
    return signal

def convert(row):
    return row['Close'] * 0.99 if row['Golden_Cross'] == "long" else math.nan

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #df = pd.read_csv('GBPUSD_MA_Crossover2.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
    
    np.random.seed(0)  # everyone will have the same (random) values

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'date': pd.DatetimeIndex([f'2024.01.{x}' for x in range(1, 21)]),
        'Open': np.random.randint(100, 200, 20),
        'High': np.random.randint(100, 200, 20),
        'Low': np.random.randint(100, 200, 20),
        'Close': np.random.randint(100, 200, 20),
        'Golden_Cross': np.random.choice(['long', np.nan], 20), 
        'fast_ma': np.random.randint(130, 170, 20),
        'slow_ma': np.random.randint(130, 170, 20),
    })
    df.index = df['date']
    print(f'{len(df) = }')
    
    long_signal = go_long_1(df)
    print(f'{len(long_signal) = }')
    print(long_signal)    

    long_signal = go_long_2(df)
    print(f'{len(long_signal) = }')
    print(long_signal)    

    long_signal = df.apply(convert, axis=1).to_list()
    print(f'{len(long_signal) = }')
    print(long_signal)  
    
    apds =  [ mpf.make_addplot(df[['fast_ma', 'slow_ma']], panel=0, title='GBPUSD'),
              # mpf.make_addplot((df['dmi']),panel=1, title='DMI'),
              mpf.make_addplot(long_signal, type = 'scatter', panel=0, markersize=200, marker='^')
            ]
    mpf.plot(df, type= 'candle', tight_layout=True, datetime_format='%Y-%m-%d', volume=False, show_nontrading=False, addplot=apds)

Result:
len(df) = 20
len(long_signal) = 20
[nan, nan, 102.96, 140.58, nan, 129.69, 99.99, 163.35, 139.59, 155.43, 133.65, nan, 144.54, nan, nan, nan, nan, 197.01, nan, nan]
len(long_signal) = 20
[nan, nan, 102.96, 140.58, nan, 129.69, 99.99, 163.35, 139.59, 155.43, 133.65, nan, 144.54, nan, nan, nan, nan, 197.01, nan, nan]
len(long_signal) = 20
[nan, nan, 102.96, 140.58, nan, 129.69, 99.99, 163.35, 139.59, 155.43, 133.65, nan, 144.54, nan, nan, nan, nan, 197.01, nan, nan]


